# how to pass data to php by using ajax .post()

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i thought i am doing the right way but don't know some how it didn't work. the remain code are all doing fine, only except i can't pass email value from the htmlside by using .post to the php page, it only shows error Undefined index mail in php page, but how?

here is my code:
HTML part:

```
  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="col-sm-12 form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text" required="" /><span id="check_msg"></span>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

    <button id="email_send" type="button" name="submit"class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

jquery part(check_email.js):

```
$("#email_send").click(function(){
    var preg = /^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/;
    var email=$('#email').val();
    if(email=='' || !preg.test(email)){
        $("#check_msg").html("Please enter a valid email address");
        $("#check_msg").css({"color":"red"});
    }else{








    $.post("forgotpasword.php",{mail:email},function(msg){

    xxxxx

})  

}
```

php code(forgotpasword.php):

$email=$_POST['mail'];

Comment: What kind of response you get in the $.post callback?

Comment: the function(msg)  basically is shows different message after user click the send button, this actually is the reset password feature, user input the email, click send, if php side found the email from the database then give the success message and send the reset link to user email, otherwise shows error message.

Comment: if i directly write $sql="SELECT uid,firstname,email,password FROM user WHERE email='q@q.com'"; (q@q.com is the test email which already installed in the database) , is working fine, but if i changes to $email, it shows Undefined index mail. i dont know why ajax can't pass data which is mail to the php page

Comment: The supplied code worked for me. What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Can you supply the code with the actual code that fetches the email-value from the form and the sql-statement? (in your question). Is it $email=$_POST['mail']; that returns an undefined index?

Comment: the version is 3.2.1, if the version is outdated the entire function shouldn't working,  currently only the data can't pass through. for the html page is already the whole code, others are not relatively with this function, i didn't use form to send the require, instead i use .post method to send, on the php side only the post function is didn't work, if i rid of the post function, others are all fine...

Comment: i even tried in js page alret(mail) is also shows Uncaught ReferenceError: mail is not defined , why is that?

Comment: I've added an answer based on your expectations of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you supplied works well: I even changed mail to mail2 just to verify that the actual value is fetched from data given from `$.post` in jquery.

**html and js:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>post demo</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#email_send").click(function(){

    var preg = /^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/;
    var email=$('#email').val();
    if(email=='' || !preg.test(email)){
        $("#check_msg").html("Please enter a valid email address");
        $("#check_msg").css({"color":"red"});
    }else{
        $.post("forgotpasword.php",{mail2:email},function(msg){
            alert(msg); //Response = dialogbox with text "Oh I forgot my 
            {actual mail I type in in form}"
        });    
    }

    });

});

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="col-sm-12 form-control" 
placeholder="Email" type="text" required="" /><span id="check_msg"></span>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button id="email_send" type="button" name="submit"class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**forgotpassword.php:**

```
<?php
echo "Oh I forgot " . $_POST['mail2'];
```

Comment: Hi, I finally got the reason, because i can't see whether php page got error or not, so i add “$(location).attr('href', 'forgotpasword.php')” in the js to force head to the php page once it been send then i could see is there any error shows in this page, but it probably just open the php page, this is why keep shows me undefined message, and i also  add  double quote on the $email( $mail->addAddress('$email', 'guest');), makes email can't send as well...now is all fixed, much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @user3528204 - aha if you redirect to a page then it's a get request. If you want to do like that you would have to supply the data in that request as well (e.g. forgotpassword.php?email={actual mailadress}). I'm glad you figured it out!